# Can't redirect from facebook embedded browser to mobile default browser

Tags: reactjs, facebook, redirect, mobile, web-applications

I'm having issues openning link to my website that I share on facebook.
By default, any link users open from facebook mobile app are opened in the facebook embedded browser.

This browser causing issues to my app so I'm trying to redirect the users to their default mobile browser, but I don't know how.
I've tried many solutions, but none have worked, the closes one was trying to do:
`window.location.href="mywebsiteurl"`, but this prompted message on facebook app that I'm trying to leaving the app, but after accepting would leave the page just idle.